# SSIS script component forgets my variables

Tags: c#, ssis

I have SSIS package with a transformation script component. It loads about 460 rows then it stops to do the script component again ( I dont know why it does this) , ofc it creates my C# class variables again and "forgets" where it was the "first time it ran" poping out nulls for the varibles.

Is there anyway make the script component not run its self again after 460 rows ? My batch that I am pulling is 10000 so it cant be that.

And the  weirdest thing of all is that after 3 times of run the package (without changing anything) it does everything right...

```
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{
    string MarkToRem;
    string TypeToRem;
    string SerToRem;
    int IDCnt;

    public override void PreExecute()
    {

        base.PreExecute();

    }
    public override void PostExecute()
    {
        base.PostExecute();


    }


    public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
    {

        MyOutputBuffer.AddRow();
          if(Row.IncomingPrice == "Mark")
          {
            MarkToRem = Row.IncomingCode ; // Setting ver to remember the mark we are in
            MyOutputBuffer.ID = Row.IncomingID.ToString();
            MyOutputBuffer.Mark = MarkToRem;
            MyOutputBuffer.Type = "";
            MyOutputBuffer.Series = "";
            MyOutputBuffer.Code = "";
            MyOutputBuffer.Price = "";
            MyOutputBuffer.Description = "Mark Verander";


          }
          else if( Row.IncomingPrice == "Sub")
          {
             TypeToRem = Row.IncomingCode; // Save our current Type
             SerToRem = Row.IncomingCode; //Save our current Series
             // ============ Output ========================
             MyOutputBuffer.ID = Row.IncomingID.ToString();
             MyOutputBuffer.Mark = MarkToRem;
             MyOutputBuffer.Type = "";
             MyOutputBuffer.Series = "";
             MyOutputBuffer.Code = "";
             MyOutputBuffer.Price = "";
             MyOutputBuffer.Description = "Sub en series verander";

          }
          else if (Row.IncomingPrice == "Series")
          {

              SerToRem = Row.IncomingCode; //Save our current Series
              // ============ Output ========================
              MyOutputBuffer.ID = Row.IncomingID.ToString();
              MyOutputBuffer.Mark = MarkToRem;
              MyOutputBuffer.Type = "";
              MyOutputBuffer.Series = SerToRem;
              MyOutputBuffer.Code = "";
              MyOutputBuffer.Price = "";
              MyOutputBuffer.Description = "Series verander";

          }

          else 
          {
              MyOutputBuffer.ID = Row.IncomingID.ToString();
              MyOutputBuffer.Mark = MarkToRem;
              MyOutputBuffer.Type = TypeToRem;
              MyOutputBuffer.Series =SerToRem;
              MyOutputBuffer.Code = Row.IncomingCode;
              MyOutputBuffer.Price = Row.IncomingPrice;
              MyOutputBuffer.Description = Row.IncomingDiscription;
          }
          IDCnt = IDCnt + 1;

    }


}
```

The first 9 rows looks like this. For the incoming data

```
ID  Code    Price   Discription
1   184pin DDR  Mark    
2   DDR - Non-ECC   Sub 
3   ME-A1GDV4   388 Adata AD1U400A1G3-R 1Gb ddr-400 ( pc3200 ) , CL3 - 184pin - lifetime warranty
4   ME-C512DV4  199 Corsair Valueselect  VS512MB400 512mb ddr-400 ( pc3200 ) , CL2.5 - 184pin -             lifetime warranty
5   ME-C1GDV4   399 Corsair Valueselect  VS1GB400C3 1Gb ddr-400 ( pc3200 ) , CL3 - 184pin - lifetime warranty
6   240pin DDR2 Mark    
7   DDR2 - Non-ECC  Sub 
8   Adata - lifetime warranty   Series  
9   ME-A2VD26C5 345 Adata AD2U667B2G5 Valuselect , 2Gb ddr2-667 ( pc2-5400 ) , CL5 , 1.8v -     240pin -    lifetime warranty
```

Comment: Added the code - note it creates the string MarkToRem; stringTypeToRem; string SerToRem; aggain because for some reason it  does the whole script component again after +- 430 rows

Comment: I've put together a reproduction package and some sample data but I'm not able to generate any run-time errors. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the issue. Could you clarify what would construe a resetting of variables? What does some of this data look like for IncomingID, IncomingCode, and IncomingPrice? Price seems generally constrained to Mark, Sub, and Series but may contain other values.

Comment: There wont be any errors , its for some reason it starts at 437 rows it starts doing the script component "from scratch" thus creating the first veribles declared at top again , and looses the value where it was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

Avoid Asynchronous Transformation wherever possible

SSIS runtime executes every task other than data flow task in the defined sequence.  Whenever the SSIS runtime engine encounters a data flow task, it hands over the execution of the data flow task to data flow pipeline engine.

The data flow pipeline engine breaks the execution of a data flow task into one more execution tree(s) and may execute two or more execution trees in parallel to achieve high performance.

Synchronous transformations get a record, process it and pass it to the other transformation or destination in the sequence. The processing of a record is not dependent on the other incoming rows.

Whereas the asynchronous transformation requires addition buffers for its output and does not utilize the incoming input buffers.  It also waits for all incoming rows to arrive for processing, that’s the reason the asynchronous transformation performs slower and must be avoided wherever possible. For example, instead of using Sort Transformation you can get sorted results from the source itself by using ORDER BY clause.